# Diz-se "arquitetado" ou "arquiteturado"?

Tags: gramática

Exemplos

> Isto está bem arquitetado.

---

> Isto está bem arquiteturado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto é `arquitetado`.

O verbo "*arquiteturar" não existe, de acordo com vários dicionários que pude checar, logo o particípio passado "*arquiteturado" tampouco existe.

Answer (score 4):

Como disse o stafusa, o verbo arquiteturar não existe.

Mas o verbo arquitetar, embora exista, não é comumente usado para descrever o trabalho do arquiteto. Um prédio está bem **projetado**.

"Arquitetar" se usa em outro contexto, e tem um significado, digamos, conspirativo:

> O José, eterno conciliador, arquitetou um encontro entre os dois inimigos, para ver se se reconciliavam.
>
> O general queria arquitetar um atentado, para atribuí-lo aos comunistas.
>
> A trama, muito bem arquitetada, resultou na queda do governo.

Comment: Esse é um bom ponto.